# Connection from Google Apps Script to SAP Business Client?

Tags: function, google-apps-script, sap-gui, netweaver

I have absolutely no experience in Apps script.
But despite it, I want to create a function to call a SAP Transaction in google sheets.

I want to mark a cell with a number in it (document number)
And then a picture, which activates a function: opening SAP Business client, chose a transaction and fills in the document number.

I hope, someone can help me.

Thanks

What I made until now, is creating a Picture with calls a function. This works.
And I found the link to the SAP Business client Software.

[image]